# React Login form not saving state correctly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, formik

I have this React Formik form for logging in.

I am using Firebase to sign in users.

For testing, I included two console.log commands, one before logging in and one after, to show the current value of the state of my login.

When the form loads, I see this console message as expected:

> **BEFORE logging in -- Am I logged in?  false**

Then I type in my email and password and hit login.

I see this console message first, which to me is odd because it's the BEFORE message:

> **BEFORE logging in -- Am I logged in?  true**

But then it says I'm not logged in again with this message:

> **AFTER logging in -- Am I logged in?  false**

So it looks like it's working but I'm not sure why it says false again right after saying true.

I feel like I have something out of order or I'm not setting the state in the proper place but I can't figure out what's going on.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Here is my form:

```
const LoginForm = () => {
    const [loggedIn, setLogin] = useState(false);

    console.log("BEFORE logging in -- Am I logged in? ", loggedIn);
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Game List Login Form</h1>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    password: '',
                    email: ''
                }}

                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password).catch(function (error) {
                            var errorCode = error.code;
                            var errorMessage = error.message;
                        });
                        actions.setSubmitting(false);
                        setLogin(true);
                        console.log("AFTER logging in -- Am I logged in? ", loggedIn);
                    }, 1000);
                }}
            >
                <Form>
                    <MyTextInput
                        label="Email Address"
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                    />
                    <MyTextInput
                        label="Password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                    />

                    <br />
                    <Button type="submit">
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </Formik>
        </>
    );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: But did you actually login? console.log will print first as it is synchronous. Therefore, does it just print out the last state?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 yes I can see myself login when using the Firebase event console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `useEffect` to check whether something actually update as this hook function will fire after rendering

```
const LoginForm = () => {
    const [loggedIn, setLogin] = useState(false);

    useEffect( () =>  console.log("my login status", loggedIn), [loggedIn]);

    // other logic...
```